# Control time anchor test

Tags: anchor-test, time

I want to control time like moving forward to a specified block or time so that we can check if the function after the block/time lasts works well. Is there any way to do that in anchor solana?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this simple check that verified that the current Blocktime is superior or equal to some Blocktime. With the help of [getBlockTime](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getBlockTime) and [getSlot](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getBlockTime)

```
while (True) {
   const currentSlot = await program.provider.connection.getSlot()
   const currentBlocktime = await program.provider.connection.getBlockTime(currentSlot)
   if (currentBlocktime > some_defined_blocktime) {
      break
   }
   sleep(1000) // sleep 1000ms before checking again
}
```

Here is how you would define the sleep function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep